# if $(X,A)$ has homotopy extension, so does $(X \cup CA,CA)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I guess I could use the property: The homotopy extension property for $(X,A)$ is equivalent to $X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I\ $ being a retract of $X\times I$.
Then there is a retraction:$$X\times I\rightarrow X\times \{0\}\cup A\times I$$
I need to show$$(X\cup CA)\times I\rightarrow (X\cup CA)\times \{0\}\cup CA\times I$$is  a retraction too. But I don't know what to do next. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(X,A)$ having the HEP implies that $X×\{0\}\cup A×I$ has the coherent topology with respect to the covering $(X×\{0\},A×I)$, that means a function from that space is continuous if its restrictions to $X×\{0\}$ and to $A×I$ are continuous on the respective spaces (so that space is homeomorphic to $M_i$, the mapping cylinder of the inclusion $i:A\to X$).

Consider the following commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}
@ X\times I \sqcup CA×I  & \longrightarrow & (X∪CA)×I \\
\downarrow r\sqcup 1_{CA} & & \downarrow r' \\
(X×\{0\}\cup A×I) \sqcup CA×I & \longrightarrow &(X∪CA)×\{0\}∪CA×I
\end{array}
$$
Since $I$ is locally compact, the upper map is a quotient map identifying
$$
\qquad\qquad (a,t)\sim([a,0],t) \qquad\qquad (1)
$$
for any $a\in A$ and $t\in I$. The map $r\sqcup 1_{CA×I}$ sends
$$(x,t)\mapsto r(x,t),\quad ([a,s],t)\mapsto ([a,s],t)
$$
where $r$ is the retraction. Finally, the lower map is defined on 
$X×\{0\}\cup A×I$ by sending 
$$
(x,0) \mapsto (x,0) \in (X\cup CA)×\{0\}, \quad 
(a,t) \mapsto ([a,0],t) \in CA×I
$$
and it is continuous by the remark at the beginning of my post.
Since the identifications (1) are respected by the lower left path, the map $r'$ is induced.

Comment: The answer seems quite hard for me right now. I'll check it every week till I succeed to understand it.Though it makes me suffer…

Comment: @Mr.Rock: I edited a bit.

Comment: Your answer is really nice. I have one small question here. How do you conclude that $r'$ is also a retraction? Has it anything to do with the commutativity of the diagram? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I understand it now. This indeed follows from the commutativity of the diagram. Very nicely written answer. Thanks. But one small point I want to mention which is that the bottom map should send $(x,0)↦[x,0].$ Because $X∪CA$ is actually a mapping cone of the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ and hence it's an identification space. The points of the identification space are usually classes of  points of some former space on which identifications are made. Isn't it so?

Answer (score 2):

Putting it more generally, if $(X,A)$ has the HEP, and $f:A \to B$ is a map, then $(B\cup_f X,B)$ has the HEP. The proof is analogous to that of Stefan, which is the case $B=CA$.

You need the method of defining homotopies on adjunction spaces, which again uses the local compactness of $I$.